# For periodical smooth $f$, is the sequence $(f^{(n)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For any infinitely differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and positive integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f^{(k)}$ denote the $k$-th derivative of $f$.

It is easy to see that for any periodical function $f\in C^\infty$ the maximum $\max(\text{im}(f))$ exists.

Is $$\big\{\max\big(\text{im}(f^{(n)})\big):n\in\mathbb{N}\big\}$$ always bounded for $f\in C^\infty$ with $f$ periodical?

Answer (score 4):

For $f(x)=\sin (2x)$ we have $max (Im (f^{(n)}))=2^{n} \to \infty$.